# Splice then re-index array in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to remove the first four indexes from the array using `splice()`, then rebuild the array starting at index 0. How do I do this?

```
Array.index[0] = 'one';
Array.index[1] = 'two';
Array.index[2] = 'three';
Array.index[3] = 'four';
Array.index[4] = 'five';
Array.index[5] = 'six';
Array.index[6] = 'seven';
Array.index[7] = 'eight';

Array.splice(0, 4);

Array.index[0] = 'five';
Array.index[1] = 'six';
Array.index[2] = 'seven';
Array.index[3] = 'eight';
```

I am accessing the array via a timer, on each iteration I want to remove the first four indexes of the array. I assumed `splice()` would remove the indexes then rebuild the array starting at 0 index. it doesn't, so instead what I have done is created a 'deleteIndex' variable, on each iteration a +4 is added to deleteIndex.

```
var deleteIndex:int = 4;
function updateTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    Array.splice(0,deleteIndex);
    deleteIndex = deleteIndex + 4;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What type of object is "Array" in the code you have shown? The Flash [Array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) object does not have a property named "index".  The Array class is `dynamic`, which means that it let's you add random properties to it at run time (which seems to be what you are doing).

In any case, if you are using the standard Flash Array class, it's [splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) method updates the array indexes automatically.  Here is a code example that proves it:

```
var a:Array = [1,2,3,4,5];
trace("third element: ", a[2]); // output: 3
a.splice(2,1); // delete 3rd element
trace(a); // output: 1,2,4,5
trace(a.length); // ouput: 4
trace("third element: ", a[2]); // output: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding what you want correctly, you need to use the unshift method of Array.

example :

```
var someArray:Array = new Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
someArray.splice(0,4);
somearray.unshift(5,6,7,8);
```

Also, you are using the Array Class improperly, you need to create an instance of an array to work with first.

The question is confusing because you used Array class name instead of an instance of an array. But as the commenter on this post said, if you splice elements, it automatically re-indexes.

Comment: Using `unshift()` is not necessary. The `splice()` method modifies the array in place, and in doing so the indexes are updated.

Comment: @Sunil D.  I know that, but the second part of his problem is inserting elements at the BEGINNING of the array, If I am understanding his issue correctly. That requires unshift(). His problem as I understand it, is that he was overwriting those values at 0,1,2,3 and he wanted to insert 4 new values at the beginning. Thus, unshift.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not understanding the question :) I thought he just wanted to remove them (the code by the OP is not quite clear).

Comment: I just modified my answer to reflect what you said, because if that is what he wants -- the only issue with the above code is him using the Class Array instead of an instance and the re-indexing was not needed.  :)  but yeah, not clear what he wants. I'll have to admit I was guessing at exactly what he was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you want to do, but Array=Array.splice(0,4) should fix somethin..

Comment: You are probably right...
To add a bit of info: Arrays are immutable, meaning that calling splice on an Array will not modify it but simply return another Array.

Comment: @MexicanSeafood [splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice()) modifies the array, it also happens to return an array ... I don't know if that's a reference to the original array or not. Point being, the original array is modified -- per the code in my answer :)